# Узнать разрядность ОС Windows в дистрибутиве (v.2)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-7, windows-8

Создал *ремэйк* вопроса:  [Узнать разрядность ОС Windows в дистрибутиве](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/7598/windowsxp), так как встретил жёсткое непонимание сути вопроса местными "специалистами".
И так, в наличии два образа Windows 7 (или 8, 10).
Как проверить в дистрибутиве, какой она разрядности?
Есть ли какая-нибудь информация об этом в файлах?
И есть ли какие-то отличительные признаки 64 bit Win7 от 32 bit win7?

---

P.S. Так и не понимаю до сих пор, за что лупят минусы, а ответов не дают?
Или все прям знают это, но молчат?
Или это так очевидно, как в математике 2x2? Не сказал бы.
Терпеть не могу таких исподтишочников! Ответ думаю показал, кто всё-таки в итоге прав.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оказалось не всё так просто, но и не сложно.  Есть файл `sourses\idwbinfo.txt`.

В 32 bit инфа такая:

```
[BUILDINFO]
BuildArch=x86А
```

В 64-х bit'ной такая:

```
[BUILDINFO]
BuildArch=amd64
```

Comment: Не обязательно. В данном файле может стоять "BuildArch=x86", но при этом будет ставиться 64-битная версия. Наблюдал такое не раз даже в официальных дистрибьюторских дисках. Наоборот - пока не встречал.